# getaddrinfo() - Linux VS Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, network-programming

In Linux, I can use a call to `getaddrinfo()` to on a local socket `getaddrinfo(NULL,port,&hints,&servinfo)` to create lists such as this:

```
   IPv4: 0.0.0.0
 | socktype: 1 |protocol: 6    IPv4: 0.0.0.0
 | socktype: 2 |protocol: 17    IPv4: 0.0.0.0
 | socktype: 3 |protocol: 0    IPv6: ::
 | socktype: 1 |protocol: 6    IPv6: ::
 | socktype: 2 |protocol: 17    IPv6: ::
 | socktype: 3 |protocol: 0
```

Whereas in windows, any call relating to the local machine `"NULL"`, `"localhost"`,`"127.0.0.1"` (actually, anything not a URL) seems to fail.

What is the intended difference in the usage of `getaddrinfo()` between linux and windows?

Also - I know this kind of makes the question a twofer - but what exactly does the output from the first program tell me?  Are those the only combinations that kernel can honor for that port?

Yes, this question is evolved from the rather famous "Beej's Guide to network programming".

The code leading up to this is such as:

```
      struct addrinfo hints,*ai,*p;

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    int error;

   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use AF_INET6 to force IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((error = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http", &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
    exit(1);
} else cout <<"Success with a URL\n";


if (error=(getaddrinfo("208.117.45.202",&port,&hints,&ai))){
       cout<<"Cannot resolve any usable ports! : "<<gai_strerror(error)<< " : "<<error;
       if (ai == NULL) return -5;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably show more code. The [MSDN docs for `getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are pretty exhaustive, it really does sound as if it should work, even for localhost.

Comment: are you sure that you are running a server on the windows platform (for example XAMPP)?

Comment: No, no server.  I was wondering if status as a server made a difference in the behavior of the `getaddrinfo()` call... but other issues have made me tend to think in terms of the OS split...

Comment: Try installing XAMPP, then run the localhost server, and try running your code, and tell us if it works :)

Comment: Something tells me I should've followed that line of thought.... thank you.  Now that I think about it, it wouldn't be necessary to get that information on something other than a server!

Comment: Did you consider using some portable free software utility (and network) library, like [QtCore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtcore-index.html) & [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html) from Qt, or [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) which would abstract those OS specific details?

Comment: I did actually .. but I've never looked at those in particular, I will, thanks.  I figured that I'd like to have at least a basic comprehension of the underlying socket system first... those libraries don't add much overhead, do they? .... If you remember a certain line from a very famous American movie: http://i.imgur.com/FlzYTja.jpg

Answer (score 2):

There are these magical things called [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html). For example, [`man 3 getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) clearly says that

> If the AI_PASSIVE flag is specified in hints.ai_flags, and node is
>   NULL, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for
>   [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)ing a socket that will [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) connections.  The returned
>   socket address will contain the "wildcard address" (INADDR_ANY for
>   IPv4 addresses, IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT for IPv6 address).  The wildcard
>   address is used by applications (typically servers) that intend to
>   accept connections on any of the hosts's network addresses.  If node
>   is not NULL, then the AI_PASSIVE flag is ignored.

The purpose of the `getaddrinfo()` function is simple: it tries its best to convert user-specified strings into numeric data an application can use to create a socket, either one listening for incoming connections, or one for connecting to.

`getaddrinfo()` is specified in [POSIX.1-2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (and [RFC 2553](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2553.txt)), and Microsoft is known for never following a standard it could extend or pervert, so of course it's a totally different function in Windows. The relevant [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says it *"provides protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address."*

The output of your program, because `node` (the first parameter) is `NULL`, and you have `AI_PASSIVE` in the flags, is the list of wildcard addresses your program can (try to) bind to, to listen for incoming connections to the `port` you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to coding consistency?

```
memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
int error;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use AF_INET6 to force IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
```

You first zero `hints` with `sizeof(hints)`; then you set some values; then you zero it again with `sizeof hints` (inconsistency); then you set some of the values a second time and miss out others (notably the `AI_PASSIVE` flag).  Programming is generally easiest if you are consistent.  It is also sensible to avoid doing (more or less) the same thing twice as you've done.  Choose one or the other sequence, but don't include both.

Whether this is actually the source of your problem is a separate issue.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438839/15168) by [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal) covers a lot of relevant ground, though I've not validated the Microsoft-specific details.

Comment: Did I let that make it to the internet?  *blushes* Yes, thank you, of course.